# readcommitted and nolock lock conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To prevent locks and deadlocks I have decided to use table hints `WITH(NOLOCK)` within my views.

That had a good effect and the users were happy with it.

The problem started when those views were called from inside an application (A CRM application called PIVOTAL).

When this application queries my views (that have `WITH(NOLOCK)` inside them) it adds a different table lock `READCOMMITTED`.

For example:

```
select * from MY_view WITH(READCOMMITTED)
```

The result of this is a SQL Server error message telling me about the conflicting locks.

Now, I cannot change the application and the way it generates its scripts.

Is there a way I could make SQL Server ignore the hint outside of `My_view`?
Is there a way to make the `NOLOCK` prevail over `READCOMMITTED`, so that I can keep it within `My_View`?

Thanks and regards.
Marcello

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy solution here. SQL Server cannot take conflicting locks as it doesn't know which locks to apply to the underlying tables.

Can you create a separate set of views for the application reading with `READCOMMITTED`?

Comment: Thanks for this Szymon, I am considering enabling snapshot isolation level for this database.